# TinyMCE multiple editors not rendering correctly in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, widget, tinymce

I'm using Yii2 and the widget from [`2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget`](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget).

The editor only looks correct when I'm using it just once, but when I'm using multiple editors the second, third, etc. editors are not rendering correctly. Do I have to stop the initialization of the TinyMCE after the first one?

Here is an example of the missed rendering:

[image]

And here is the code where I'm using the widget:

```
<?php

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => $ansichtAktiv->id,
            'enableClientValidation' => true,
            'action' => 'index.php?r=empf/ansichtspeichern&geraet_token=' . $geraet->token . '&ansicht_id=' . $ansichtAktiv->id
        ]);
?>
<?=

$form->field($ansichtAktiv, 'html')->label('Ansicht:')->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
    'language' => 'de',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'plugins' => [
            "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
            "textcolor",
        ],
        'toolbar' => "forecolor backcolor | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    ]
]);
?>
<?=

$form->field($ansichtAktivSec, 'html')->label('Ansicht2:')->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
    'language' => 'de',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'plugins' => [
            "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
            "textcolor",
        ],
        'toolbar' => "forecolor backcolor | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    ]
]);
?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Speichern', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'speichern-button']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Does your console show any errors?

Comment: no, im sorry there aren't any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a new JavaScript file and add this part of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
    });
});
```

Once the document is loaded, tinyMCE will initialize all TinyMCE plugins that have a type of `textarea` (default).

---

If you prefer writing inside view file, then add this at the bottom of it:

```
$this->registerJs('
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
    });
', View::POS_END);
```

Comment: sorry i have an other question, i have multiple editors, so how can i set diffrent ids of the editors?

Comment: @tgrafen1 Simply add `'id' => 'some_id' at the same level as `'clientOptions' => [`. That should work.

Comment: im sorry but the id still remains the same in like the activeForm. but i need diffrent ids so i can change the content via JS

Comment: @tgrafen1 It might be then `'options' => ['id' => 'some_id'],`

Answer (score 1):

You have two fields with the same name (`html`). By default Yii generates field ID based on field name. If you have two fields of the same model with the same name, they will have the same IDs. If `TinyMce` widget uses ID to initialize TinyMCE editor, only first element with this ID will be initialized.

You should use different names (for example `html` and `html2`) for these fields or specify ID manually:

```
$form->field($ansichtAktivSec, 'html', [
    'inputOptions' => ['id' => 'html-1'],
])
```