# How to add 2amigos CKEditor in dynamic form in YII2?

Tags: jquery, yii2, ckeditor, tinymce, dynamicform

I have tried to integrate text editor using `yii2-dynamicform`.
I tried https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget.

Then I tried https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget which had the first row initialized. Subsequent rows don't get initialized.

I just want, when add more form through dynamic form then ckeditor show in that form that run time generate through jQuery

I have the following as the snippet inside the widget foreach loop:

```
<?= $form->field($modelBlock, "[{$i}]description")->widget(CKEditor::className(), [ 'options' => ['rows' => 3], 'preset' => 'basic' ]); ?>
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

[image: image is here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TinyMCE multiple editors not rendering correct yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171188/tinymce-multiple-editors-not-rendering-correct-yii2)

Comment: how to implement with ckeditor

Comment: i add tiny but problem still here

Comment: @yasirshah Did you find the solution for this question?